# How to query a JSON MySQL column into a dict?

Tags: python, json, pymysql

My database looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table( irrelevant_column TEXT, json_stuff JSON );
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;

+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| irrelevant_column      | json_stuff                                    |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| blah blah              | { 'this': 'is my json data' }                 |
| more unrelated stuff   | { 'more': 'of my data in the correct format' }|
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for an elegant way to query JSON data from MySQL into a list of dicts.

I have tried using a `DictCursor`

```
cursor = connection.cursor( pymysql.cursors.DictCursor )
cursor.execute( "SELECT json_stuff FROM my_table" )
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

but it doesn't properly handle the JSON column type. It returns this:

```
[
  { "json_stuff": "<json_stuff row 1 in string format>" },
  { "json_stuff": "<json_stuff row 2 in string format>" }, 
  etc.
]
```

I would like

```
[
  { 'this': 'is my json data' },
  { 'more': 'of my data in the correct format' }, 
  etc.
]
```

This ugly and inefficient code works.

```py
def get_list_of_stuff():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "SELECT json_stuff FROM my_table" )
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return [ json.loads( row["json_stuff"] ) for row in rows ]
```

Does anyone know a way to do this without looping through all of the rows and parsing each one into JSON?

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the JSON stuff as a string, and then reading it in via the `json` module?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy That's what the final code snippet does.

Comment: `this` and `more` are keys in the JSON data in the `json_stuff` column.

Comment: I've added a sample of the data inline.

Comment: It works with but one extra line, that's not "ugly" in my books. And it's rather efficient in terms of time spent on writing it. Please specify your requirements.

Comment: I'm looking for a "native" way to go directly from MySQL-native JSON format to Python-native JSON format.

Note that this is possible when going in the other direction (`INSERT`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySQL developers apparently don't consider it appropriate for drivers to automatically convert between the JSON data type and Python structured types. A bug report [JSON columns should accept Python dicts as input](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88995) was submitted a couple of years ago. It was closed as "Not a bug", with the comment:

> Because JSON is not a built-in type (or even type in Python). This kind of conversions shouldn't be made in a driver, is better suited for frameworks that have an high level of abstraction.

Since you're not using a framework, just a low-level database API, you need to do the parsing yourself.

Peronally, I disagree with their reasoning, and I think your expectation is reasonable. But that's the way it is.

Comment: The discussion in that report is interesting and captures the spirit of what I'm trying to do. With sad trombone music I'm afraid I must accept this answer.

Comment: Always sorry to be the bringer of bad news.